# "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: x field does not exist" showing up after I delete model field

Tags: python, django

I deleted the field `total_comments` from my `Post` model. I performed `migrate` and `makemigrations` on my local server, pushed the migration files to my remote server, and then performed `migrate` and `makemigrations` there aswell. However I'm now seeing this error in my remote server terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/james/postr/post/tasks.py", line 18, in arrange_ads
    for ad in ads:
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 899, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 889, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column post_post.total_comments does not exist
```

I've checked my migration folder in `myapp/post/migrations` and it shows that the migration file is definitely there:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('post', '0031_auto_20180804_0724'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='post',
            name='total_comments',
        ),
    ]
```

So why am I still getting this error...any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The error was occurring on my celery task which involves dealing with my `Post` model (although the celery task file didn't do anything with `total_comments`).

I restarted the celery server and now the error has gone.